# How do I load Bing Maps in Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, html, ajax

Using the following code on a Visualforce page does not load the map:

```
<apex:page doctype="xhtml-1.0-transitional" showHeader="true" sidebar="true">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0&s=1"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetMap()
        {
            var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), {credentials:"My_Secret_Bing_Maps_Key"});
        }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="GetMap();"> 
        <div id='mapDiv' style="position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;"></div>
    </body>
 </html>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Visualforce does not preserve your body `onload` replacing that with its own logic. (Worth using your browser's "View Source" or "Inspect" feature to look at the HTML that the Visualforce is translated into.)

You can use this [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) approach instead:

```
<script>
window.onload = GetMap;
</script>
```

that does result in the map being displayed.

Answer (score 3):

Keith C is right. `<body onload=` will not work. You can call your `GetMap` method from `window.onload` as below. I just updated your code and it is working. Also you **need a key** to use the Map.

```
<apex:page doctype="xhtml-1.0-transitional" showHeader="true" sidebar="true">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0&s=1"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetMap(){
            var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapDiv"), {credentials:"My_Secret_Bing_Maps_Key"});
        }
        window.onload = function() {
            GetMap();
        };        
        </script>        
    </head>
    <div id='mapDiv' style="position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;"></div>
 </html>
</apex:page>
```

Screens:-

[image]

Comment: It is not working.:)

Comment: @AndrejsIgumenovs It is working for me. Please find the above scrrens. As I mentioned you need a key to get the actual result.

Comment: Sorry, I put the `window.onload` outside the `<script>` content. You're right, thanks!!!